# Writing files to external SDCard -android

Tags: android

I have been trying to write files from my app to the external sdcard , however it doesn't write it , my test phones are galaxy duos and LG , when I tried on LG phone it works just fine , however the LG phone has android version is 4.1.2 .while the galaxy is 4.4.2 , I guess this has something to do with the SDCard changes in kitkat 4.4 , wondering if anyone could solve it ??

Answer (score 0):

In 4.4 the application can not write data to any place on the external SD card. The application can write the data only to certain folders on the external card (under /extSdCard/Android/data/ path). This is a new restriction imposed by Google that is supposed to allow users to delete all data associated to the application after the application is uninstalled.

Here's the [detailed explanation](http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes).

Answer (score 0):

With Android 4.4 (KitKat), Google blocked apps from writing to the SD card except for a very specific sandboxed location. Apps have direct write access **ONLY** to their package-specific directories as obtained through Context.getExternalFilesDirs(), Context.getExternalCacheDirs(), etc.  "Direct" access is defined as using traditional file access APIs, like POSIX open().  Direct access to the remainder of these secondary external storage devices remains read-only for apps.

However, apps can create/write files outside of their package-specific directories on secondary external storage devices by using the new CREATE_DOCUMENT intent, which involves the user in the file creation process.

Notably, Google’s Nexus devices do not include micro SD card support; however, many other Android-powered devices do feature micro SD card functionality. The previous version of Android left devices vulnerable from a security standpoint, but Google has now addressed these safety concerns by limiting what third-party apps can do with a Micro SD card.

Comment: `the new CREATE_DOCUMENT intent, which involves the user in the file creation process.`. Nice. I've heard those words before. What do you mean with `involves`? Did you ever try this yourself? Please give a working code example.